# For what value of k does the following system of linear equations have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been struggling for hours trying to solve this: For what value of k does the following system of linear equations have infinitely many solutions?

$$x+y+kz=3$$
$$x+ky+z=-7$$
$$kx+y+z=4$$

Comment: What have you been trying so far to solve the problem? How can you relate the problem to the determinant of the coefficient matrix? or have you tried Gaussian elimination?

Comment: I have been trying Gaussian elimination and trying to get an all zero row but have failed

Answer (score 3):

The system of equations can be written as a matrix:$$\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&1&k&3\\
      1&k&1&-7\\k&1&1&4
    \end{array}
\right] $$
Find the determinant of the coefficient matrix and we get $-k^3+3k-2=0$
In order for the solution to be infinitely many solutions, the determinant must be 0. If det(A) = 0, that means at least one of the rows is a linear combination of the other rows.

So $-k^3+3k-2=0,k=1$

Comment: If $k=1$ then there are no solutions.

Comment: We have not learned determinants yet, and 1 was actually one of the answers i arrived at before but it was not correct

Comment: It is easy to see that if $k=1$, then there are no solutions. If you have not learned determinants yet, then it seems you are supposed to use Gaussian elimination. However, as you see with the case when $k=1$, even using determinants, you still need to go back and check whether the resulting values that correspond to a zero determinant give infinitely many solutions or no solutions.

Comment: I'm not really looking for the answer just how to get it i suppose because i know it is -2

Comment: $k=-2$ is also a zero for the determinant.

Answer (score 1):

The augmented matrix for the system is

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1&k&3\\1&k&1&-7\\k&1&1&4\end{bmatrix}.
$$

After a 3 steps of Gaussian elimination we arrive at

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1&k&3\\0&k-1&1-k&-10\\0&0&-k^2-k+2&-3k-6\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Looking at what values will produce a row of zeros in rows 2 or 3, we see that $k=1$ results in the equation $0=-10$, giving no solutions. On the other hand if $k=-2$, then the last row results in $0=0$, giving infinitely many solutions. All other values of $k$ give a unique solution.

Comment: thank you! that was the matrix i arrived at but wasnt sure what to do from there. appreciate the help

Comment: You're welcome. In the future, try to add more details about what you have tried and more specifically about where you are stuck so it is easier for folks on here to help you.

Comment: alright. also another question why wouldn't 4 work? never mind:P

Comment: Then we have $-18 = -18$ in the last row, giving $z = 1$, back substituting from there gives a unique solution.